# array of pointers to static doubles in C++ function

Tags: c++, c, static

I'd like to have an array of pointers to static data. For instance

```
  void func(...) {
     ...
     static int mysize = initial_size;
     static double* d[3] = {new double[mysize], new double[mysize], new double[mysize]};
     for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
        if(cond) {
           //-re-allocate d if necessary.
           use d here;
        }
        else {
           use d here;  //-since d is static; it persists and so this is justified?
        }
     }
     //-Can I get away with not deleting d here??
  }
```

My reasoning is that since d is an array of pointers to static doubles; it is allocated once inside a function and so when everything goes out of scope, it is hopefully deleted? I somehow think not. This is probably wishful thinking and leads to memory leaks?

Perhaps I am better off using a static C++ vector here? I want to use a static here in order to re-use the previously computed and stored data in d, when some conditions are met (e.g. if some condition such as cond or its negation is satisfied). Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: It will never get deallocated, but it lasts the lifetime of the process anyway, so who cares?

Comment: @ildjarn: Glad someone thinks like me.. but still, some corner of me is a bit concerned. Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AdamLiss said above, you could leak memory at the *re-allocate d if necessary* step if you're not careful to delete the existing arrays before re-allocating:

```
void func(...) {
  static int mysize = initial_size;
  static double* d[3] = {new double[mysize], new double[mysize], new double[mysize]};
  for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(cond) {
      d[i] = new double[2*mysize];  // LEAK!
      use d here;
```

Even if you remember to delete it like this:

```
void func(...) {
  static int mysize = initial_size;
  static double* d[3] = {new double[mysize], new double[mysize], new double[mysize]};
  for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(cond) {
      delete[] d[i];
      d[i] = new double[2*mysize];
```

there's a bug, because the new allocation could throw an exception, leaving `d[0]` pointing to deleted memory, but no way to tell that, so when the function next gets called if `d[0]` is dereferenced it will be undefined behaviour.

This would be OK:

```
void func(...) {
  static int mysize = initial_size;
  static double* d[3] = {new double[mysize], new double[mysize], new double[mysize]};
  for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(cond) {
      double* tmp = new double[2*mysize];
      std::swap(tmp, d[i]);
      delete[] tmp;
```

But you would avoid such issues if you used a vector to manage the dynamic memory:

```
void func(...) {
  int mysize = initial_size;
  typedef std::vector<double> dvec;
  static dvec d[3] = {dvec(mysize), dvec(mysize), dvec(mysize)};
  for(int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
    if(cond) {
      //-re-allocate d if necessary.
      d[i].resize(2*mysize);
      use d here;
    }
    else {
      use d here;
    }
  }
}
```

This also has the advantage of being able to query the existing size, via `d[i].size()` and not having to manually copy elements from the old array to the new one when reallocating

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing actually long before you posted... sorry, I didn't revisit the page since posting my question. But since you answered it the way I ended up resolving the issue, I am voting this to be the answer. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

It would be an error to delete `d`, because it was not allocated with `new`.  However, since the individual elements *are* allocated with `new`, you need to be careful to avoid orphaning their memory.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "you need to be careful to avoid orphaning their memory"? Are you referring to the comment of possible reallocation? Because I personally do not see problems with not deleting statics (as ildjarn has stated above).

Comment: The elements of `d` are not statics, they are pointers to memory from the heap, and if you assign new values to those elements you will leak the memory they previously pointed to.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely Ah I think I see what you mean. So if I interpreted correctly, you are saying that `static int * a[1] = { new int(42) }` is unsafe, but `static int const * a[1] = { new int(42) }` would be okay?

Comment: @Wakely: Each element of d in the array is a static double*; if I was changing their size, I'd ofcourse delete and then re-allocate, but they're still static, so I think they persist in memory upto the end of the process. Agreed that some memory is leaked in the process, but how else would one deal with static pointers in C++  functions?

Comment: @nijansen, no. That would still leak if you later do `d[0] = new int` without first doing `delete d[0]`. You should be careful about the difference between `int const *` and `int * const` see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.5

Comment: @squashed.bugaboo, no, the array itself has static storage duration but each element of the array is `double*`. As long as you delete the pointers before reallocating that's OK though.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely You're right. Thanks for your explanation and the helpful link.

Answer (score 1):

Your code's basically ok, though there are implications:

- memory-usage checking tools like purify, insure and valgrind might report more noise about potential memory leaks, but that in and of itself is only noise.
- `static` makes it harder to create thread-safe code - having the caller pass `d` down as a function parameter to `func` allows thread-specific copies, application-area specific copies, easier unit testing without having to restart the process, and full client control of lifetime.
- Say your application introduces an additional stage/phase where after finishing with calls to  `func()` it starts doing some other memory-intensive calculations before shutdown - the memory will still be allocated.  That may not matter to you, particularly if you've plenty of virtual address space and can let it be swapped out to disk, but it's an extra potential maintenance issue as the code evolves.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments. Will try and keep these in mind.